# Does LIKE and = treat withespaces the same way in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a strange phenomena when running a `MySQL` query that has some conditions with `LIKE` and `=`.

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    ...
WHERE
    products.productcode LIKE '590082QRV040'
    AND ...
```

For some reason in the database some productcodes are stored with a space character at the end (presumably the lack of trimming somewhere the data being inserted). So for example the productcode above is actually stored as `'590082QRV040 '`. The strange thing is if I run the query with conditions like: `products.productcode LIKE '590082QRV040'` there is no match, but for `products.productcode = '590082QRV040'` I got the desired result. I'm just wondering what is the reason. I thought the difference between `LIKE` and `=` is that wildcards are allowed in `LIKE`. But now I don't even have wildcards so the two should act exactly the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html) is rather clear on this point:

> Per the SQL standard, LIKE performs matching on a per-character basis,
>   thus it can produce results different from the = comparison operator:
>
> . . .
>
> In particular, trailing spaces are significant, which is not true for
>   CHAR or VARCHAR comparisons performed with the = operator:

I strongly advise you to fix the data:

```
update products p
    set p.productcode = trim(p.productcode);
```